When are Idempotents elements of a semisimple algebra primitive
Let $A=KG$ be a $K$-algebra such that $|G| \in K^{\times}$. Here $A$ is a semisimple algebra. Consider the decomposition of $A$ into simple components:$$A=A_1 \times A_2 \times \cdots \times A_k.$$
For $1 \le i \le k$, let $e_i$ be the unity of the simple algebra $A_i$ and $T_i:A \to \text{End}_K(V_i)$ be irreducible representations of $A$ with character $\chi_i$.
Falko Lorenz on page 261 of his Algebra book Volume II says: $e_1, e_2, \cdots e_k$, which are uniquely determined by $A$ (apart from their order), are called the primitive central idempotents of $A$. They satisfy
$$e_1+ \cdots+ e_k=1 \ \text{and}\ \ e_ie_j=\delta_{ij}e_i.$$
In the page 264, he proves: $$e_i=\frac{\dim_K(V_i)}{\dim_K(\text{End}_A(V_i))|G|}\sum_{g \in G} \chi_i(g^{-1})g.$$
Now, consider any representation $T: A \to \text{End}_K(V)$, with decomposition $$V=V_1^{n_1}\oplus \cdots \oplus V_k^{n_k}.$$ According to Serre's representation theory book, if $K=\mathbb{C}$ and $V_i$ are given in matrix form $(r_{\alpha \beta}(g))$ with respect to an orthogonal basis, then $\chi_i(g) = \sum_{\alpha}r_{\alpha \alpha}(g)$, and $$p_{\alpha \alpha}=\frac{\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(V_i)}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} r_{\alpha \alpha}(g^{-1})T(g)$$ is a projection; it is zero on $V_j^{n_j}$, $j\ne i$. Its image $V_{i,\alpha}$ is contained in $V_i^{n_i}$, and $V_i^{n_i}$ is the direct sum of the $V_{i,\alpha}$ for $1 \le \alpha \le n_i$.
My question is what $$e_i(\alpha,\alpha):=\frac{\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(V_i)}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} r_{\alpha \alpha}(g^{-1})g$$ are in the algebra $\mathbb{C}G$?
It seems to me that $e_i$ is not a primitive idempotent since $$e_i=\sum_{\alpha=1}^{n_i}e_i(\alpha,\alpha).$$ Does it contradict what Lorenz said in his book?!
Here, $T\left(e_i(\alpha,\alpha)\right)$ is a projection. Should $e_i(\alpha,\alpha)$ be an idempotent or not necessarily?

I'm not yet 100% sure, but a possibility that occured to me is that may be you get non-central idempotents. Or idempotents in $End(V_i)$? The latter may be more likely given that $r(g)$ describes the action of  $g$ on $V_i$ only. It actually looks like $e_i(\alpha,\alpha)$ is not an element of $\Bbb{C}[G]$ at all. We can, of course, map $End(V_i)$  into the corresponding Wedderburn component within $\Bbb{C}[G]$.

You know that $End(V_i)\simeq \mathcal{M}n(\Bbb{C})$, $n=\dim V_i$. In that matrix algebra $I_n$ is the only central idempotent, but we can write it as a sum of idempotents $I=\sum{j=1}^ne_{jj}$, when the $n$ copies of the irreducible module $V_i$ are each the left ideals generated by $e_{jj}$, $j=1,\ldots,n$. Of course, there is nothing canonical about that decomposition, because we only have left ideals as opposed to 2-sided ideals. After all, the $e_{jj}$ depend on the choice of basis (once we think of them as elements of $End(V_i)$.

I would do the following: Calculate an example! To keep it manageable size yet relevant, you need to pick a small group with an irreducible rep of dimension $\ge2$ so that the Wedderburn components are not just copies of $\Bbb{C}$. Somehow $S_3$ and its 2-dimensional rep suggest themselves :-)

How do you say $e_i(\alpha, \alpha)$ is not in $\mathbb{C}G$? $r_{\alpha,\alpha}(g) \in \mathbb{C}$ for each $g$. So, $e_i(\alpha, \alpha)$ is a linear combination of elments of $G$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$, and thus $e_i(\alpha, \alpha) \in \mathbb{C}G$

In your example, $I_n$ is the only central idempotent. Is it also primitive? Each $e_{jj}$ is idempotent also $e_{11}, \cdots, e_{nn}$ are mutually orthogonal. Here, we can decompose $I_n$ into a sum of orthogonal idempotents. So, can we say $I_n$ is not primitive?

At least in the context of group algebras over $\Bbb{C}$ primitive central idempotent means that such an idempotent cannot be written as a sum of two orthogonal central idempotents. In the case of the matrix algebra, the matrices $e_{jj}$ are not central.

Yeah, it was a mistake to think of $e_i(\alpha,\alpha)$ as not living in the group algebra. Sorry about that.

I got it. Thank you.

Based on the comments, a primitive central idempotent is a central idempotent that cannot be written as a sum of two central orthogonal idempotents. If we define that a primitive idempotent is an idempotent that cannot be written as a sum of two orthogonal idempotents, then a primitive central idempotent is not necessarily a primitive idempotent.
In my problem, $e_i(1,1),\cdots,e_i(n_i,n_i)$ are mutually orthogonal idempotents, but they are not central since $r_{\alpha\alpha}:G \to \mathbb{C}$ is not a class function.
So the fact that, $e_i=\sum_{\alpha=1}^{n_i}e_i(\alpha,\alpha)$ does not contradicts $e_i$ being primitive central idempotent.
